# Check if piwik tracking code is installed

Tags: javascript, matomo

I have made a dashboard where users of my site can download a javascript tracking code for their own websites, using Piwik.

As of now I can only tell if a user's tracker is working properly if there is data incoming from their end. But is there any way to check if the code has physically been installed in the website? I need this to differentiate between users who have the code installed but have no visits since, and users who have not installed the code at all.

Cannot find anything in the piwik documentation that handles this particular problem.

Comment: You could `wget` or `curl` the page and check if the tracking code has been added to the page.

Comment: Oh, I assumed the code would not show up as it is an active script. Thanks, I will try this and write back with the results!

Comment: Hey thanks this works!

Comment: I've added some code to the above comment, if this works for you please indicate it as solution - so it might be useful for other SO users. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `PHP` you could use:

**Using `file_get_contents`**

```
$url = 'website URL to check';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
// check if tracking code available
if (strpos($data, 'PIWIKTRACKINGCODE') !== FALSE){
    echo 'TRACKING CODE FOUND';
} else {
    echo 'TRACKING CODE NOT FOUND';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

**Or using `curl`**

```
$url = 'website URL to check';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch)
// check if tracking code available
if (strpos($data, 'PIWIKTRACKINGCODE') !== FALSE){
    echo 'TRACKING CODE FOUND';
} else {
    echo 'TRACKING CODE NOT FOUND';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php